# Migrate fields to another site?

Tags: 8, database, emails

I have a Drupal 8 site with a contact form that has a lot of fields. I need to duplicate these fields onto another Drupal 8 site but can't find where they are stored in the DB.

In the config table there is a row per field, but when I try to copy these across, I get this message:

> Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Attempt to create a field my_field_name that does not exist on entity type contact_message. in Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig->getFieldStorageDefinition() (line 286 of core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php).

Does anyone know if it's possible to copy the contact form fields to another site via the Database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One way could be:

1. You export your configuration. (drush cex -y, or on the interface configuration management)
2. You filter the configuration you need.
3. You import those configuration files into the other site (drush cim, or manually).